# Liblinear Error

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm, liblinear

I am training my datasets in Liblinear: train heart_scale, but i am getting this error

```
can't open /home/linguistics/.train//train.ini
ERROR: Init file not found (/home/linguistics/.train//train.ini)
train>
```

Reference: 
README file from Liblinear's source code. I downloaded it from here:
http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/cgi-bin/liblinear.cgi?+http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/liblinear+tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try  ./train dataset_name   instead of  train dataset_name